# ASP.NET_SessionId access denied

Tags: python, asp.net, api, python-requests, rest

I'm trying to write a code which collects data from website using REST API.
There is an authentication and I correctly send POST request (let's name it *LogIn*) with credentials and correct response. Then, I would like to call another POST command (let's name it *GetData*), but I get "Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials."

I'm using python `requests.session()` to keep all cookies and I've noticed something wired. If I log in the web browser and replace ASP.NET_SessionId cookie in my python *GetData* request (like that: `self.session.cookies.update({'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'XXX'})`) the response is correct.

I've checked and python *LogIn* request also generates ASP.NET_SessionId cookie but somehow it is not valid and only if I copy it from browser it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a feasible short-term workaround to manually append headers from the Login response onto subsequent requests, rather than using `requests.session()`?

Comment: when I copied headers from the LogIn response to the GetData request I'm getting: "Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID...". For sure it's something new but I don't know if this is step forward or backward ;)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

**You do not keep/send the authentication cookie from login to the next call.**

When you call the login page the login is answer with an authentication cookie, and maybe with a session cookie.

On the next call you have to provide this two cookies to been able to get the data - the one is assure that you have the permissions to read them